# jQuery - fading img change

Tags: jquery, class, image, fade

here my code which works perfectly but i want that the change from the img tag and the new class will be smoothed fade in when the mouse is over the button. Is that possible?

**jQuery:**

```
        $('.hover').mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).next().removeClass('hide')
            var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "_hover.svg";
            $(this).attr("src", src)
        });     

        $('.hover').mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).next().addClass('hide')
            var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("_hover.svg", ".svg")
            $(this).attr("src", src)
        });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="facebook">
           <a href="#">
            <img class="fb_logo hover" src="img/facebook_logo.svg" alt="Facebook Logo" />
            <img class="fb_text hide" src="img/facebook_text.svg" alt="Facebook Text" />
          </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it seems you want a simple fade-in/fade-out image switcher. Here's one approach:

```
<div class="facebook">
<a href="#">
    <!-- Start with one image on the page. We'll change the src attribute with JavaScript -->
    <img src="https://dmcohen01.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/5b2145c4aakermit.jpg"/>
</a>
</div>




// Now for the JavaScript:
$('img').mouseenter(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    self.fadeOut('slow', function(){
        self.attr('src', 'http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100831164753/muppet/images/7/70/Firstmatepiggy.jpg').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

$('img').mouseleave(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.fadeOut('slow', function(){
         self.attr('src', 'https://dmcohen01.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/5b2145c4aakermit.jpg').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle with it working: http://jsfiddle.net/brianeoneill/uTpWp/

Comment: thanks a lot. this is what i need. is a crossfade between both img´s possible?

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean. By "cross fade" you mean you want to see one fading in as the other is still fading out?